# Where to init MutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I've tried to init/alloc it in initWithFrame but then objects wouldn't get added.

It'd only work in this method I'm calling but I call this method each time user refreshes the view so it'd init/alloc hundred times.
Not sure why it won't just work in initWithFrame.

I need to know the right way to init and add..!

```
-(void)queryParseMethod {

self.imageFilesArray = nil;
self.imageFilesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[self.imageFilesArray addObjectsFromArray:objects];

if (!error) {

    for (PFObject *object in objects) {

        int index = (int)[self.favArray indexOfObject:[object objectId]];
        [self.imageFilesArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:object];

    }

    [self.favCV reloadData];
}}
```

Comment: Is `imageFilesArray` a weak property?

Comment: No its just default.

Comment: Why doesn't it work in `initWithFrame`? What is the problem?

Comment: I'm not really sure. It returns null if I init it in initWithFrame and add objects in the method. It does return everything when I init/add both in the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just:

```
if (self.imageFilesArray == nil) {
    self.imageFilesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.imageFilesArray addObjectsFromArray:objects];
}
```

And make sure that `imageFilesArray` is a strong property.

Comment: Right on. Should've thought of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your most likely problem is that `initWithFrame:` isn't being called. If this view comes out of a storyboard, then you need to put this in `awakeFromNib`, since storyboard/nib-loaded objects initialize with `initWithCoder:`, not their designated initializer.

You generally don't want to try to do initialization in `initWithCoder:` because it's called too early. `awakeFromNib` is called after all your IBOutlets are assigned.

It is very common for experienced devs to break initialization out into its own method like this:

```
- (void)setup {
   // Do your setup here
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self setup];
    }
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self setup];
}
```

Doing it this way makes sure that the object is initialized in either case.

Another common solution is lazy initialization, particularly for things like `NSMutableArray`:

```
@interface MyView
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSMutableArray *imageFilesArray;
@end

@implementation MyView

- (NSMutableArray *)imageFilesArray {
    if (_imageFilesArray == nil) {
        _imageFilesArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    return _imageFilesArray;
}
```

Comment: I'm doing everything programmatically and also everything else in initWithFrame is being called... So I've no idea what's going on.

Comment: You should dig into that then. You may be looking at the wrong instance of your view. I wouldn't just patch this at the usage site; it's probably masking a deeper bug.